# How to set tax rates and rules to the products with GST in India

Tags: magento-2.1

In India, the old sales tax, vat everything comes under GST.

Can anybody explain with an example, how to set a tax rate and rules to each product?

Comment: This is Magento2 GST extension, for those who want plug and play solution
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-indian-gst.html

Answer (score 2):

you need to create 2 types as **CGST and SGS**T for within states and **IGST** for all over india. please go through below link for more details  :

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-indian-gst-tax-rule-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

you should refer to this blog post
http://www.credevator.com/how-to-configure-gst-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set Indian GST Tax Rules using Default Magento 2 Settings. The easiest method to setup GST would be using an Extension such as: https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-indian-gst.html

Comment: It is possible to setup GST tax configuration in Magento 2

Comment: Yes, it is. But has many limitations: https://meetanshi.com/blog/apply-indian-gst-in-magento-2/

Comment: I have configured it and didn't find any limitation for myself.

Comment: Can you please share the guide you have used or maybe you can describe how you have done it. It will be helpful for the community.

Comment: You can follow steps given here.. http://www.credevator.com/how-to-configure-gst-in-magento-2/ let me know if face any hurdle configuring it